# How to add a custom header into coming request on server?

Tags: java, request, jetty, request-headers, http-request-parameters

I am using a Jetty 11 server which has a GET method called getObject().

When I receive a request on the server, I want to add a custom header to create a unique identify for the request. So I am trying to add something like `x-request-id` with value obtained using UUID into the header.

I tried doing a pseudo search in the header itself using -

```java
        final String requestId;
        if (!StringUtil.isEmpty(request.getHeader("request-id")) && !StringUtil.isEmpty(request.getHeader("request-id"))) {
            requestId = request.getHeader(request.getHeader("request-id"));
        }
        else {
            requestId = UUID.randomUUID().toString().toUpperCase(); //.replace("-", "");
        }
        request.setAttribute("Request-ID", requestId);
        System.out.println("requestId - " + requestId);
```

But this does not seem to get added into the header of the request.

My ultimate target is to forward this request outside the server with this `x-request-id` as my request switched the environment. Once I receive a response, I want to do some lookup on this request later.

My method looks like this -

```java
public void handle(String target, Request jettyReq, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        // Redirect API control based on HTTP method type
        if (request.getMethod().equals(constGetRequest)) {
            doGetObject(jettyReq, request, response);
        }
        jettyReq.setHandled(true);
    }
```

How do I achieve this with the `HttpServletRequest` request in jetty?

Comment: Are asking how to extract a custom header on the server, or how to specify a custom header on the client? `HttpClient` is a Java class used by *clients*. `HttpServletRequest` is an interface used on *servers* for getting information sent by a client. Your question is very confusing, so please **edit** the question and clarify what you're asking about.

Comment: @Andreas thank you for the request. Yes, this is essentially on the server. My handler code has httpServletRequest where I want to add the header. Sorry for the earlier confusion. I just edited the quesion as per your suggestion.

Comment: @Andreas I am aware of the fact that HttpServletRequest type is read-only and that is why I am confused about how to solve this.

Comment: What do you mean ‘add the header to the request on the server’? Do you want to send the header back to the client (put it on the response); or just add some context for the rest of your application (just add it to the environment in one of any number of ways: other arguments, threadlocals, a map of properties)?

Comment: @BeUndead Oh! I want to use it to do a response. What is actually happening is a request is made to my API X. X then does some operation and forwards the request to a different env running with Python. Python server responds to the request with 200 Ok but not with actual data request indented. instead it calls another method Y on my server. Y is not supposed to respond to the original request. But to make this happen, I need to do a look up on the request in Y's logic. Therefore I need to keep something in the header of the my request. Does this make the scenario clearer?

Comment: So you're saying that your Java web server is sending an HTTP request to a Python web server, and that you want to add a custom header to the request sent from Java to Python? If so, then understand that the Java `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` are not used for sending a request on to the Python web server, you'll be using `HttpClient` for that. --- If you want to send a custom header *back* to the original client, then you'd use `HttpServletResponse` for that. You would not be using `HttpServletRequest` for any of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using embedded Jetty, use the built in `org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.Listener`.

You'll have access to the raw internal Jetty `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request` object that has the HTTP Fields for that request.

To use it, you'll create an instance of that `HttpChannel.Listener`, and add it as a bean to your connectors.

```java
MyChannelListener channelListener = new MyChannelListener();
connector.addBean(channelListener);
```

There are many events that the listener exposes, you'll probably want to set the `X-Request-ID` during the `void onRequestBegin(Request request)` event.

If using Jetty 9.x you can use the following ...

```java
@Override
public void onRequestBegin(Request request)
{
    request.getHttpFields().put("X-Request-ID", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
}
```

If using Jetty 10.0.0+ (including Jetty 11), the `request.getHttpFields()` is an immutable object.  You'll just have to intentionally yank it out, modify it, and replace it, like this ..

```java
@Override
public void onRequestBegin(Request request)
{
    HttpFields.Mutable replacement = HttpFields.build(request.getHttpFields())
        .put("X-Request-ID", UUID.randomUUID().toString().toUpperCase());
    request.setHttpFields(replacement);
}
```

Read the javadoc on `HttpChannel.Listener` and pick other things that might fit your needs.

Then all other access of that request, be it internal components of Jetty, a webapp, a specific servlet, filters, forwarding, includes, error handling in the servlet spec, error handling outside of a servlet context, etc can all see it.

The only types of requests you wont see on this, are ones that fail the Request line and/or low level Header/Field parsing steps, those will be reported as BadMessageExceptions to the server level error handler.